# Dynamically changing parameter values every 5 minutes in Agent Based Modelling in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on an Agent Based Model where I have a Agent Population of 1, and have the following parameters 1. BPM 2. Temperature 3. Glucose Level

I am trying to figure out a way to manually vary the value of parameters every 5 minutes. For example,

1. At time t1, the value of BPM is 60.
2. At time t1+5 minutes the values of BPM should vary between (50-100)

And this should go on till the end of the model. Any suggestions on how to simulate this?

Comment: Check how Dynamic Events (not Events!) work. They allow you to do just that.
PS: You should not vary parameters at runtime, this is what variables are for (the name gives it away ;) )